# React PropTypes DOM element?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

How do I mark a property as having to be a DOM element?

[This page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) says that `PropTypes.element` is actually a *React* element, so what's the equivalent for *DOM* element?

Comment: Do you mean type of DOM element? Checking for a specific type could be done with a custom prop checker against `someNode.constructor.name`.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst No, I mean *any* DOM element. `div`, `span`, `input`, whatever.

Comment: `React.PropTypes.node`?

Comment: div, span, input are also react elements. They get translated to DOM elements only later.

Comment: @vijayst Even if they're fetched with `document.getElementById` or created with `document.createElement` and **not** `React.createElement("input")`?

Comment: @elmeister `node` is too loose. It includes numbers, strings and arrays.

Comment: React.PropTypes.node logs a warning Failed prop type: Invalid prop

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
PropTypes.instanceOf(Element)
```

Is working for me. You can also add isRequired:

```
PropTypes.instanceOf(Element).isRequired
```

Comment: Is there a nodejs equivalent?

Comment: You can now use `PropTypes.elementType` as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007326/what-is-the-correct-proptype-for-a-ref-in-react/51127130#51127130

Comment: Expanding this answer to include the difference between how to do it with a div vs an imported component could get you some extra rep, just saying

Comment: You should avoid using this if you SSR your app because `Element` will be `undefined` in nodejs. If you strip out your PropTypes from your production build you will be fine there. But even so, you'll throw an error in the development build.

Comment: @Pandaiolo `PropTypes.elementType` is NOT for native DOM element instances. See here: https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/issues/334 and here: https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/pull/211

Comment: @sydd thanks for pointing that. This comment is from 2019 and cannot be edited, _however_, my answer that I mention _was_ updated around that time, as per my comment to svnn that you also reacted to. Let me know if you see any obsolete content left.

Answer (score 7):

You can check if the passed property is instance of `Element`:

> The Element interface represents an object of a Document. This interface describes methods and properties common to all kinds of elements. Specific behaviors are described in interfaces which inherit from Element but add additional functionality. For example, the HTMLElement interface is the base interface for HTML elements, while the SVGElement interface is the basis for all SVG elements.

```js
class Some extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div> Hello </div>
    );
  }
}

const validateDOMElem = (props, propName, componentName) => {
  if (props[propName] instanceof Element === false) {
    return new Error(
      'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
      ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
    );
  }
}

Some.propTypes = {
  htmlElem: validateDOMElem,
};

const para = document.getElementById('para');

ReactDOM.render(<Some htmlElem={para} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
<p id="para"></p>
```

Comment: It is also possible not to create a custom validator and use `PropTypes.instanceOf(Element)`

Answer (score 6):

For example with a list component:

```
MyList.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.instanceOf(<li></li>),
}
```

Works for me.

Comment: I get warning `Failed prop type: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable` if I use this, does this not work anymore in 2019?

Answer (score 5):

`PropTypes.instanceOf(Element)` will not work for server-side render, because of `ReferenceError: Element is not defined`

Suggest using `PropTypes.object` instead