# What is the correct proptype for a ref in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am storing a ref in my redux store and using mapStateToProps to expose the ref for components that need access to it.

The ref that is stored looks like:

```
ref={node => this.myRefToBePutInReduxGlobalStore = node}
```

What is the correct propType for this ref?

Comment: Because refs aren't serializable, it's not a good idea to put them into Redux store. Nonetheless, the value passed to `ref` prop is a function with the first argument a reference to DOM element or null. [It's a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element).

Comment: You cannot use `propType ` for `refs`, but you can use it for `props`. Since you are passing it to redux store then it's represented as a `prop` like `this.props.myRefToBePutInReduxGlobalStore`. `myRefToBePutInReduxGlobalStore` should be the type of node, so `PropTypes.node` should work for you

Comment: I think it should be `PropType.object` because ref is basically class instance which is object. Hence when you pass ref element as a props it would be of _object_ type

Answer (score 183, accepted):

## TL;DR

**If you want to prop type a ref that only expects native DOM elements, such as a `div` or an `input`, the correct definition is the following:**

```js
refProp: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    // Either a function
    PropTypes.func, 
    // Or the instance of a DOM native element (see the note about SSR)
    PropTypes.shape({ current: PropTypes.instanceOf(Element) })
])
```

## Answer to the specific issue described in the original post

In the OP question's example, it is not the ref prop type that needs to be declared, but the stuff pointed by the ref, and that will be passed from redux using `mapStateToProps`. Prop type for a DOM element would be: `myRefToBePutInReduxGlobalStore: PropTypes.instanceOf(Element)` (if it's a DOM element). Although, I would:

1. Rename it to `myElementToBePutInReduxGlobalStore` (an element is not a ref)
2. [Avoid storing non-serializable data inside redux store](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.84.0/lib/react.js#L231)
3. [Avoid passing elements in props](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/15157#issuecomment-505090728) as explained by React engineer Seb Markbage

---

## Long answer to the actual question

*Q: What is the correct proptype for a ref in React?*

Example use case:

```js
function FancyInput({ inputRef }) {
    return (
        <div className="fancy">
            Fancy input
            <input ref={inputRef} />
        </div>
    )
}

FancyInput.propTypes = {
    inputRef: ???   // What is the correct prop type here?
}

function App(props) {
    const inputRef = React.useRef()
    useLayoutEffect(function focusWhenStuffChange() {
        inputRef.current?.focus()
    }, [props.stuff])
    return <FancyInput inputRef={inputRef} />
}
```

---

Today, two kind of refs exist in react:

1. An object which looks like this: `{ current: [something] }`, usually created by
   `React.createRef()` helper or `React.useRef()` hook
2. A callback function which will receive `[something]` as its argument (like the one in OP example)

*Note: historically, you could also use a string ref, but [it's considered legacy](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) and will be removed from react*

The second item is quite simple and requires the following prop type: `PropTypes.func`.

The first option is less obvious because you might want to specify the type of element pointed by the ref.

## Many good answers

`ref` can point to something else than DOM element.

**If you want to be totally flexible:**

```js
refProp: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.func, 
    PropTypes.shape({ current: PropTypes.any })
])
```

The above just enforces the shape of object ref w/ `current` property. It will work at all time for any kind of ref. For the purpose of using prop type, which is a way to spot any inconsistencies *when you develop*, this is probably enough. It seems *very unlikely* that an object with shape `{ current: [any] }`, and is passed to a `refToForward` prop, would *not* be an actual ref.

**However**, you might want to declare that your component does not expect *any* kind of ref, but only a certain type, given what it needs that ref for.

*I have setup a sandbox showcasing a few different way to declare a ref, even some non conventional, and then testing them with many prop types. [You can find it here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-benz-w6fbh).*

---

**If you only expect a ref pointing to a native input element, not *any* HTML `Element`:**

```js
refProp: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.func, 
    PropTypes.shape({ current: PropTypes.instanceOf(HTMLInputElement) })
])
```

**If you only expect a ref pointing to a React class component:**

```js
refProp: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.func, 
    PropTypes.shape({ current: PropTypes.instanceOf(Component) })
])
```

**If you only expect a ref pointing to a functional component using `useImperativeHandle` to expose some public method:**

```js
refProp: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.func, 
    PropTypes.shape({ current: PropTypes.object })
])
```

*Note: the above prop type is interesting because it also covers react components and native DOM elements, because they all are inheriting the base javascript `Object`*

---

**There is no single good way to declare the prop type for a ref, it depends of the usage. If your ref points to something very identified, it can be worth adding a specific prop type. Otherwise, just checking the general shape seems enough.**

---

## Note about server side rendering

If your code has to run on the server, unless you already polyfill DOM environment, `Element` or any other client-side type will be `undefined` in NodeJS. You can use the following shim to support it:

```js
Element = typeof Element === 'undefined' ? function(){} : Element
```

---

The following React Docs pages gives more insight [on how to use refs, both object and callbacks](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs), and also [how to use `useRef` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

*Answer updated thank to @Rahul Sagore, @Ferenk Kamra, @svnm, and @Kamuela Franco*

Comment: It gives `Element` is not defined on server side rendering. Any solution to that?

Comment: Good point. What about this shim: `Element = typeof Element === 'undefined' ? function(){} : Element` (suggested by Ryan Florence in some github issue). If it works for you I can add it to my answer.

Comment: I figured it out and added this `if (!isBrowser) {
  global.Element = null;
}`. Worked for me. `isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';`

Comment: Great answer. I would love the TL;DR to be at the top of the response.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS. Element is undefined on production builds(specifically gatsby builds). you should better explain from where you imported this `Element`

Comment: @EliavLouski there's a note at the bottom of my answer about SSR and how to pollyfill `Element`. Also I'm surprised that proptypes declaration are not removed in production bundle, as React only use them in dev mode.

Answer (score 25):

Very similar to @Pandaiolo's post,

`PropTypes.elementType` has now been added

```
forwardedRef: PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.func,
  PropTypes.shape({ current: PropTypes.instanceOf(Element) })
]),
```

`PropTypes.instanceOf(Element)` looks to be the correct way to do this now as mentioned by Ferenc

Comment: Thanks @svnm, I have updated my answer to reflect this, which makes it simpler!

Comment: In the end, that `elementType` was not working for me, so I actually tested a bunch of prop types on different kind of components that can be pointed by a ref, in a sandbox. Here are the results: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-benz-w6fbh. I'm not sure I covered all possibilities, but it seems that the correct proptype for DOM element is `instanceOf(Element)` (or `object`), for a class it is `instanceOf(Component)` (or `object`) and for the specific use case of a functional component using `useImperativeHandle` it is `object`. Thoughts?

Comment: This does **not** work, its a wrong answer. `PropTypes.elementType` is used to check if a prop is a React element type, not a native DOM element. See here: https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/issues/334 and here: https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/pull/211

Answer (score 10):

I only check for the preferred way and since *PropType.object* is not very valuable I ended up using this:

```
PropTypes.shape({ current: PropTypes.instanceOf(Element) })
```

Answer (score 4):

I checked all the above answers but I get a warning from the react, so I researched a lot and I got the right answer.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

ComponentName.propTypes = {
  reference: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.func,
    PropTypes.shape({ current: PropTypes.instanceOf(Component) }),
  ]),
};
```