# Correct PropTypes type when passing a ref in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What is the correct way to specify the *label* prop (a ref created with React.createRef() )?

```
const MyComponent = ({ label, initValue }) => (

        <TextInput
          style={styles.textStyleNumber}
          ref={label}  // <-----------------------------
          editable={false}
          defaultValue={initValue}
        />
        ...
)

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  // label: ? ,
  initValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct proptype for a ref in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007326/what-is-the-correct-proptype-for-a-ref-in-react)

Comment: Hi, I saw the links you provided, I thought it was different since this is in React Native, also I've tried the solutions, but it gives me the warning 'Element' is not defined. Should I just import it from 'react-native' ? Thank you

Comment: `Element` is not available in react native. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 MyComponent.propTypes = {
    label: PropTypes.shape({ current: PropTypes.instanceOf(TextInput) }),
    initValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
label: PropTypes.shape({component: PropTypes.instanceOf(React.Component)})
```

or like abadalyan answered, try this:

```
label: PropTypes.shape({ current: PropTypes.instanceOf(TextInput.__proto__)})
```

Just tried with a RNCamera ref, seeing if (this.camera instanceof React.Component) and it returned true.